# Left join of various queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, ssms, tableau-api

I am currently working on Tableau software and need to do a custom SQL query.

I currently have two tables, each of them being the result of an SQL query.

TABLE 1:

```
Select * 
from AA 
left join BB on AA.id = BB.id
```

TABLE 2:

```
Select * 
from CC 
inner join DD on CC.brandId=DD.brandId 
where CC.Year between year(getdate())-4 and year(getdate()) 
      and CC.productCategoryId  = 'Category 1')
```

I would like to do a query which is:

FINAL QUERY:

```
Select * 
from TABLE 1 
LEFT JOIN Table 2 on AA.id = CC.id (both have id)
```

But I does not work. SQL Management server is giving me an error on the LEFT JOIN of the final query and I don't understand why... It's like it is not letting me create the left join (both requests for Table 1 and 2 work fine, it is adding them up which does not work).

Any idea?? :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: and whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Replace TABLE 1 with AA and Table 2 with CC.

Comment: Hi A, I just get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'"...

Hi dcp, I need to get the info from AA left join BB and CC left join DD. AA left join CC is not going to give me all the information I need.

Comment: don't think its that easy since `table 1` is no valid name and has two columns named `id` same goes for table 2

Comment: `Select * 
from [TABLE 1] AA 
LEFT JOIN [Table 2] CC on AA.id = CC.id`

Comment: So how should I proceed?

** Edit ** Oops didn't see JaydipJ's answer. Thanks :) Quick question, will doing this though give me a new table with the values from AA and CC only? And I will lose the columns from BB and DD?

Comment: You don't need to use custom SQL for this. You can define the relationships and join keys in Tableau's data pane. Save custom SQL for specialized problems, not standard joins. Otherwise, you inhibit Tableau from optimizing the queries it sends.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you put the results from AA into a new Table named Table 1, and likewise from CC to Table 2, it does not make sense to query for AA.id=CC.id.
Try domething like [Table 1].id=[Table 2].id

Comment: Hi Marius

Thanks a lot. How do I specify the [Table1].id? Currently I'm basically just inserting the SQL query for Table 1 in my final query. So I don't have a name for the query.
I'm doing this to put in the Tableau software custom SQL request so I'm not sure that naming works for this.

Comment: I don't know Tableau, but you could try to nest your queries:

Comment: I don't know Tableau, but you could try to nest your queries:

Select * from

(Select * from AA left join BB on AA.id = BB.id) Tbl1

left join

(Select * from CC inner join DD on CC.brandId=DD.brandId 
where CC.Year between year(getdate())-4 and year(getdate()) 
      and CC.productCategoryId  = 'Category 1')) Tbl2

on Tbl1.id = Tbl2.id

Logic is: select  creates a temporary table which we now alias with Tbl1 and Tbl2, and then perform the query.

Comment: Hi Marius,
Thanks a lot I will give it a try! Even though I'm doubtful that Tableau allows nesting temporary tables. I think it only allows for basic select queries

Comment: Happy to help. You think you could upvote my solution? I need some positive feedback..

Comment: Sorry I was sure I had upvoted it. I clicked on the little up arrow but I still see 0... :( I think I have not a high enough ranking or something